# BigQuery - IFERROR for standardSQL

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-code

I'm about to migrate queries from Legacy to Standard in BQ.
In Legacy I used to have `x/y` returning `null` if `y=0`, however, I'm stuck in StandardSQL with the error:

> Error: division by zero

I'd like to apply something like `IFERROR(x/y,null)`

Is it available in StandardSQL?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In standard SQL you can use `SAFE_DIVIDE(x, y)`
It is an equivalent to the division operator (/). Returns NULL if an error occurs, such as division by zero.

Comment: Official docs here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#mathematical-functions